# Replace/change text of a button but leave inner html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a button with an icon:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    People <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

I want to replace the text `People` and leave the html part of the button.

I have a situation that may require some flexibility. I may not know the inner html of the button.

The resulting html would be something like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Jeff <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

I do happen to be using jQuery and if I do:

```
$('button.dropdown-toggle').text('Jeff');
```

Obviously that will remove the caret. I don't want to remove the caret.

I know that I can get the caret by doing `.children()`. But I won't necessarily know what order the html element would be in. Maybe the caret is first, or maybe it was placed after the text, it could be in any order. What if there are two icons? I want to only replace the text of the button and leave the html.

I don't usually have control of the HTML that will be in the button.

Comment: I don't understand if you truly have no vision into the HTML except that there is a '.caret' span after the text you're wanting to change, why you would expect even that fact to hold true.  Isn't it just as likely they'll add an image, or formatting, or any sort of update to the content beside 'People'?

Comment: Can you even be sure there only ever will be only one text node to replace and that it will never come wrapped in an HTML element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may not need jQuery for this.

If the position of the text node is known, you can just access the `.caret` element's previous sibling text node and change the value directly:

```js
document.querySelector('.btn .caret').previousSibling.nodeValue = 'Something';
```

```css
.caret {
  display: inline-block; width: 0; height: 0; margin-left: 2px; vertical-align: middle; border-top: 4px dashed; border-top: 4px solid\9; border-right: 4px solid transparent; border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    People <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

---

Alternatively, if the position of the text varies, you could also just use the `.content()` method to retrieve the children elements and text nodes. Iterate over the values and determine if it is a text node and change it.

```js
$('.btn').contents().each(function() {
   if (this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim()) {
     this.textContent = 'Something';
   }
})
```

```css
.caret {
  display: inline-block; width: 0; height: 0; margin-left: 2px; vertical-align: middle; border-top: 4px dashed; border-top: 4px solid\9; border-right: 4px solid transparent; border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    People <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: The reason i don't like this answer is that it silently puts constraints on the structure of the content to be replaced ( that it be a text node ).  Why not just give it a tag and address as such?  It's more straight forward and far more robust in the face of HTML changes all around the target content.

Comment: @DanFarrell And how does your answer differ?

Comment: Ah, my answer puts a tag around the _target_ of the dynamic content update.  And why not?  Why insist that it's a text node?  My anwer does appear to be a duplicate of @devpro's, however.

Comment: @DanFarrell Well, the OP said *"I don't have control over the HTML that will be used."*, which is why I provided a second solution.

Comment: Valid point, but knowing the selector for the target of your dynamic javascript update is a valid - indeed, a powerful - contract between design end and scripting end.  I suppose there's probably some valid reason you might not want to have such a contract.

Comment: This is, however, the most flexible answer regarding the restrictions already given by the OP. It only relies on semantic hierarchy, which is the only thing that seems to be (relatively) clearly defined.

Answer (score 3):

You can change like that to add an inner span for button name:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
 <span id='innerBtn'>Jeff <span>
<span class="caret"></span>
</button> 

$("#innerBtn").html('TEXT CHANGE');
```

If you don't have access on your HTML than try this:

```
$('.btn btn-default').html($('.btn btn-default').html().replace('Jeff','TEXT CHANGE'));
```

Comment: Yeah, I really like this answer.  flexible and robust in the face of design changes.

Comment: I don't have control over the HTML that will be used.

Comment: @johnston than u can try this $('#one').html($('#one').html().replace('text','replace'));

Comment: The replacement will fail as soon as the original text content of the button changes, as well as after executing this once.

Comment: @wortex17 can we do this with regex? I dont knw about the regex in jquery... but have knowledge in php

Comment: @devpro Imho if you begin regexing HTML, you are better off using Joshs answer, as the closest thing you are going to achieve with regexes is a string based variant of it.

Answer (score 3):

Put "People" itself in a tag and change the contents of that tag.  This can accommodate more changes in the HTML inside the button without ensuring that the only text, the first text, the caret's sibling, etc is the element to replace, and regardless of whether the text 'People' changes.

```js
document.querySelector('.btn .target').innerHTML = 'Something';
```

```css
.caret {
  display: inline-block; width: 0; height: 0; margin-left: 2px; vertical-align: middle; border-top: 4px dashed; border-top: 4px solid\9; border-right: 4px solid transparent; border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class='target'>People</span> <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var strNewString = (your class name or div name).html().replace('people','Jeff');

your class/div.html(strNewString);
```

This will replace the string **'people'** with **Jeff**.

Comment: This works, but it is incredibly inflexible.  Once you add any additional content that can't easily be matched by a regular expression, or simply want to vary the text dynamically, a text based replacement brakes down.

Answer (score 0):

try, something like this.

```js
function change() {

  var c = $("button").children();
  $("button").text("second ").append(c);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="change()">first <span>Span</span>
</button>
```

Comment: OP dont have access on HTML